# Effective matrix in functional programming

Tags: matrix, scheme, racket, sicp

I am C/C++ programmer and I started learning Racket / reading SICP. I have a question about effective representation of matrices in functional programming.

1. What is the most effective representation for matrices in functional programming? Old good array of arrays? I am asking because SICP authors use lists of lists for matrices.
2. Here is a real-world problem: in our production code we have function which sets random values to matrix cells on each step. The simplified code looks like this:

> // up to N random cells initialized with random values
>
> // matrix is a current state of the game field

```
for (n = 0; n < Random(N); n++)
{
    matrix[Random(X)][Random(Y)] = Random(MAX);
}
```

This code is simple and effective. How to write this code effective in functional style for a large immutable matrix? Is it possible? If yes, then how?

Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Óscar said, the most traditional functional programming approach would be to use linked lists. However, a more direct (albeit with some mutation) approach would be to use vectors.

However, since you mentioned you were doing this in Racket, you can actually use [`for/vector`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html?q=for%2Fvector#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2Fvector%29%29) to make your matrix. You can either either use a vector of vectors, as in:

```
(define my-matrix
  (for/vector ([i (in-range 3)])
    (for/vector ([j (in-range 3)])
      (random))))
```

which makes a 3x3 vector of random numbers. Now you can use [`vector-ref`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/vectors.html?q=vector-ref#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._vector-ref%29%29) twice to get an element out of it.

```
;; Evaluates to the middle most cell in the matrix
(vector-ref (vector-ref my-matrix 1) 1)
```

Another approach you can do is to take a C-like approach, and use a single vector for the whole matrix. This requires you to store an extra argument for the width of course, but can make things a bit cleaner.<sup>1</sup> For example, you could make a 3x3 matrix that contains the numbers 1 through 9:

```
(define matrix-width 3)
(define matrix
  (for/vector ([i (in-range 1 10)])
    i))
```

And now you only need a single `vector-ref` to get your element:

```
;; This also gets the middle most cell.
(vector-ref matrix (+ 1 (* 1 matrix-width)) ; => 5
```

Of course, if you want to do this a lot, it make sense to wrap this into a single data-structure:

```
(struct matrix (width data))
(define (make-matrix width height)
  (make-vector (* width height)))
(define (matrix-ref m i j)
  (vector-ref (matrix-data m) (+ i (* j (matrix-width m)))))
(define (matrix-set! m i j v)
   (vector-set! (matrix-data m) (+ i (* j (matrix-width m))) v))
```

Of course, you could go even further, and with a little more work and a small macro and you can even add `for/matrix` and `in-matrix` as looping constructs, as well as matrix math library. But at some point you will have effectively made the [`math/matrix`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/math/matrices.html?q=math%2Fmatrix) library which comes with typed racket.<sup>2</sup>

<sub><sup>1</sup>Of course this is purely subjective, and will also depend on your program.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup>Technically it also works with standard, untyped, Racket, but much slower.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am ok with the imperative approach, I was just curious how things are solved in a functional way. Maybe I can ask Haskell-guys, they live in immutable world :)

Answer (score 1):

The authors of SICP want to teach computer science, specially functional programming. There interest is NOT to show the different tools in the GNU/MIT-Scheme interpreter. Since 40 years I love SICP as an inspiration.
You should use vectors!